# Story involving authority figures, children riding bikes on the beach, and pog wizards

Tags: story-identification

Several years ago, amidst a search for something completely unrelated, I stumbled across a strange website that had an excerpt of some fiction next to a scan of a book cover.

The excerpt detailed an exchange between a "pog wizard" and an authority figure of some sort, as a child slowly rode a (magical?) bicycle into the ocean behind them.

Upon searching for it again, using the same search, I was unable to find it when I had time to fully appreciate it's absurdity - and now that I do have that time I can't even remember what I'd searched for.

Needless to say, searching for "pog wizard" hasn't been fruitful, hence asking here - does anybody know what the heck I read?

Comment: Only one book (series) on Google Books has the term "Pog Wizard"; https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pog+wizard%22 but this appears to be a transcription error since it's not to be found in the books themselves

Comment: Is it possible you've misremembered the phrase *pog wizard* and it was something similar? It's such a distinctive phrase that it seems surprising Google cannot find it if the phrase was there.

Comment: There do exist in fantasy works "[dog wizard](https://www.google.com/search?q=dog+wizard&tbm=bks)" and "[bog wizard](https://www.google.com/search?q=inauthor%3A%22Donita+K.+Paul%22+bog+wizard&tbm=bks)"; is it possible it's one of those?

Comment: The pictured book cover from the google link doesn't begin to remotely match my memory - the image accompanying the page I encountered was a scanned cover of a rather well-read paperback and quite a distinctly more 70s-80s style of illustration.

Comment: I'm quite confident that I didn't misread or misrecall the phrase - I'm not the only interested party trying to figure out just what we saw/read. The page came up sometime in early-mid 2016 as a tangent to a search distinctly about pogs - particularly a rumor that they were somehow related to silverware. Alas we had just enough time to glance through the absurd text and confirm to one another "yes, that's definitely talking about 'pog wizards' - is this for real?" before moving on with the day and forgetting about it for several years.

Comment: Could "pog" be the internet slang term from minecraft, as explained in https://theencarta.com/what-does-pog-mean/ ? There even is a skin named "Pog wizard" (https://www.minecraftskins.com/skin/17514825/pog-wizard/), but the term "Pog wizard" does not appear to have specific meaning beyond "a wizard that is pog" (i.e. exceptionally good).

Comment: It could well have been a fanfiction written about the book who's cover image was on the page. It even may have been using "pog" in the sense of current internet slang - though it predates my encounters with it by a few years - but it quite literally was a short (and absurd) fiction about a "pog wizard". Out of all the details I can recall, that was the most impressively outlandish one which I found remarkable.